# Input field dosen't appear in the view - Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring, model-view-controller

I want to show information from my database in my page jsp so I create this method :

```
public Agent getInfo(int ppr){
       final String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT NOML,PPR,LL_Fonc,LL_CADRE,NOM_ETABL,cina,cinn from activite_agent WHERE PPR=?";

        RowMapper<Agent> mapper=new RowMapper<Agent>(){

            public Agent mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)throws SQLException {
                Agent ag = new Agent();
                ag.setPrenomarabe(rs.getString("LL_FONC"));
                ag.setNomlatin(rs.getString("NOML"));
                ag.setPpr(rs.getInt("PPR"));
                ag.setCadre(rs.getString("LL_cadre"));
                ag.setNomarabe(rs.getString("NOM_ETABL"));
                ag.setCina(rs.getString("CINA"));
                ag.setCinn(rs.getInt("CINN"));
                return ag;

            }   
        };
        return (Agent)getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(ppr) }, mapper);

   }
```

and this is the controller where I call this method above :

```
@RequestMapping("servicebyPPR")
    public String getService(@RequestParam("ppr") Integer ppr,ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute Movement movement){
        if (ppr==null) {
            model.addAttribute("Noinsertppr", true);
            return "FicheService";}
            else{
                if (actservice.IfFound(ppr)==true){ model.addAttribute("notfoundppr","true");}
                else{
            model.addAttribute("agact", actservice.getInfo(ppr));
           // model.addAttribute("agserv", actservice.getServices(ppr));
                }
            return "FicheService";

            }
    }
```

here i want to show some information :

```
            <tr>

                                <td><form:input type="text" value="${agact.cina}"
                                        path="cina" /></td>
                                <td><form:input type="text" value="${agact.cinn}"
                                        path="cinn" /></td>

                                <td><form:input type="text" value="${agact.ppr}"
                                        path="ppr" /></td>
                                <td><form:errors path="ppr" Class="errorbox" /></td>
                            </tr>
```

Now the problem is that just Two input appears in my view and the input of "ppr" is hidden i don't know why ?

[image]

Comment: 1. When this page is loaded on the browser, can you do a view page source and check if the html mark up for "ppr" is generated?
2. Are there any errors on the server log?

Comment: I have no error in my console and in the source page i can't find the 3 filds ! not just ppr

Comment: When I just write <c:out value="${agact.ppr}" /> I can see it in my page but until i put it into an input filed it become hidden

Comment: The issue is certainly on the server side. Look into your application server/servlet container's log. If you are using tomcat it will be at (in most cases) $CATALINA_HOME/logs. Also for kicks, try <input type="text" value="${agact.ppr}"/>.

Comment: Thanks for comment :) when i show the source code of my page, the input exists and the value that i want to pass passed safely. by  the way this field will be hidden so i don't care i it appear or not.